# Android app icon doesn't look the way it should

Tags: image, android-studio, icons

I am about to add an icon to my android app.
I use the image assest feature in Android studio, follow all the steps, and run my app in my phone (Android Oreo), but the problem is that the image appears really focused in the round icon.
[image: My Image Icon]
[image: How it looks on the Phone]

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using going to [this website](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) . Go to launch icon generator and import the image you want. Download the zip file and extract it into your project. I tried this with the picture you provided here and it works for me. Let me know if anything else pops up.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot and let you know, thank's by the way

Comment: Thank's man, I had a problem with my mipmap files, had to delete them and start over from the beginng, and it works.